# Subscription feed email displays a tag incorrectly

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

This happened for the "WatchKit" Stack Overflow tag.
[image]
Here is the corresponding question: [Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_WKInterfaceController error after updating XCode to version 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506391/undefined-symbol-objc-class-wkinterfacecontroller-error-after-updating-xcode).

Comment: That's an odd way to render [`watchkit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) indeed.